# Dynamic replacement of path in template via python tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, templates, replace, tkinter

I'm using tkinter for building a GUI in my python script. In this python script the user must connect to some paths. One path is the source (template) and the target the path for writing the content of the template and replacing some variables. 
In python the variable is for example:

```
self.filename1 = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title="open...", filetypes=[("Text Files","*.txt")])
```

In the python script I have used the replace method:

```
replacements = {'%p%':'self.filename1')
```

or

```
replacements = {'%p%':self.filename1),
```

but without the desired result by replacing the path with the content after putting a path with filename like 'C:/Users/Frank/Desktop/Test/template.txt'.

Has anyone any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: both of the `replacement = ` lines use a open curly bracket `{` and a close round bracket `)` which is a syntax error, I'd assume just from typing in the question.

Comment: I do not understand the sentence, `One path is the source (template) and the target the path for writing the content of the template and replacing some variables.` Is it possible you are missing a few word?

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen You're right, the bracket at the end must be a curly bracket. I must explain more what exactly I have to do. In Python I have several paths, that I want to replace when reading from the template to writing to a text file: In Python the path names a stored in a variable via tkinter. In the python script I have to open the paths from the tkinter module like:`txt_in = open(self.filename1, 'r')` `txt_out = open(self.filename2, 'a')`. What I want is the dynamic path name that is saved in the variable filename1 e.g. 'C:/Users/Frank/Desktop/Test/template.txt' and replace them.

Comment: if you are opening the second file for appending `'a'` then it will add to the file instead of replacing it, is it possible you just want to change the `'a'` to `'w'`?  (NOTE: when you open a file in mode `w` it erases the previous file so be sure to make back ups as necessary)

Comment: Or if you are looking to make replacements within the text you may just need the `str.replace` method:  `data = txt_in.read() ; txt_out.write(data.replace("%p%",self.filename1)`,  run `help(str.replace)` for description of method or look at `import re ; help(re.sub)` if execution time is relevant.